# Authentication failing for MongoEngineResource with ReferenceField

Tags: django, mongoengine, tastypie

The request to the embedded field of MongoEngineResource doesn't go through Authentication process, if it contains reference field.

My case is the following:

- there is a document Section, which consist of FieldDefinitions
- FieldDefinitions are EmbeddedDocuments
- FieldDefinition contains `embedded_section` (optional), which references to the Section, and there is a signal that excludes self-referencing (e.g. embedded_section can only reference to the section, which doesn't contain the FieldDefinition)
- this all is a part of moderator's interface, so i use authorization for all kinds of requests (get, post, patch, etc.)

Here is the code:

```
from tastypie_mongoengine.resources import MongoEngineResource
from tastypie.authentication import ApiKeyAuthentication
from apps.api.auth import CustomAuthorization

class FieldDefinitionResource(MongoEngineResource):
    embedded_section = ReferenceField(attribute='embedded_section',
                                      to='myproject.apps.api.resources.SectionResource',
                                      full=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        object_class = models.FieldDefinition # mongoengine EmbeddedDocument
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = CustomAuthorization()

class SectionResource(MongoEngineResource):
    fields = EmbeddedListField(attribute='fields',
                               of='myproject.apps.api.resources.FieldDefinitionResource',
                               full=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        object_class = models.Section # mongoengine Document
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = CustomAuthorization()
```

So, when i'm asking for a Section detail (e.g. /api/v1/section/524df40502c8f109b07ed6ae/), everything goes smooth, and `fields` attr is being displayed correctly in both cases of the presence and absence of `embedded_section`.

But an attempt to refer to a specific field (e.g. /api/v1/section/524df40502c8f109b07ed6ae/fields/0/) throws an error:

```
error_message: "'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'has_permission'"
```

has_permission is a method of MongoUser, which inherits from Django auth.User. In the first case described (Section detail) it does go through Authentication and fills request.user with a proper user object, while in the second case (Section field) it skips Authentication stage entirely, going straight to Authorization.

Am i doing something wrong?

Here is a full traceback:

```
{"error_message": "'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'has_permission'", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/var/www/vhosts/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 195, in wrapper
    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/var/www/vhosts/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie_mongoengine/resources.py", line 277, in dispatch_subresource
    return resource.dispatch(request=request, **kwargs)

  File "/vagrant/myproject/myproject/apps/api/resources.py", line 248, in dispatch
    super(FieldDefinitionResource, self).dispatch(request_type, request, **kwargs)

  File "/var/www/vhosts/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie_mongoengine/resources.py", line 776, in dispatch
    self.instance = self._safe_get(bundle, **kwargs)

  File "/var/www/vhosts/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie_mongoengine/resources.py", line 768, in _safe_get
    return self.parent.cached_obj_get(bundle=bundle, **filters)

  File "/var/www/vhosts/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 1113, in cached_obj_get
    cached_bundle = self.obj_get(bundle=bundle, **kwargs)

  File "/var/www/vhosts/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie_mongoengine/resources.py", line 528, in obj_get
    return super(MongoEngineResource, self).obj_get(bundle=bundle, **kwargs)

  File "/var/www/vhosts/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 2069, in obj_get
    self.authorized_read_detail(object_list, bundle)

  File "/var/www/vhosts/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 589, in authorized_read_detail
    auth_result = self._meta.authorization.read_detail(object_list, bundle)

  File "/vagrant/myproject/myproject/apps/api/auth.py", line 201, in read_detail
    bundle.request.user.has_permission('read_detail',

  File "/var/www/vhosts/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 205, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)

AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'has_permission'
"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue in django-tastypie-mongoengine: see 
https://github.com/wlanslovenija/django-tastypie-mongoengine/issues/71

https://github.com/wlanslovenija/django-tastypie-mongoengine/issues/72

and https://github.com/wlanslovenija/django-tastypie-mongoengine/issues/70

Those 3 issues are about the same problem:

The Authentication is being performed only before the action itself, but not before actions on a resource prior to the target action.

Example (using the code in my question): the target action `update_detail` of the instance of FieldDefinitionResource, which is a child of SectionResource. Prior to updating a detail of FieldDefinitionResource, there is a `read_detail` of SectionResource - and this is an action, for which django-tastypie-mongoengine skips the Authentication stage. It results in the absence of request.user, which in its turn prevents the work-flow from moving towards the target action (update_detail of the child resource).

This applies for EmbeddedDocumentField, EmbeddedListField, ReferencedListField and ReferenceField.

One possible workaround is to override the authorization for embedded / referenced document:

```
class CustomAuthorization(Authorization):
    def read_detail(self, object_list, bundle):

        # Double-check anonymous users, because operations
        # on embedded fields do not pass through authentication.
        if bundle.request.user.is_anonymous():
            MyAuthentication().is_authenticated(bundle.request)

        # Now authorize.
        try:
            return bundle.request.user.has_permission(object_list, 'read_detail')
        except AttributeError:
            raise Unauthorized(_('You have to authenticate first!'))
```

But of course, it would be nice to have it solved in the future releases.

Comment: (Maintainer of the package in question): Please make a pull request with tests. I myself am using the package only for public read-only APIs so authentication has been completely untested and underdeveloped. As you can see. :-)